# Instagram Scraping [python]

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

I am creating Instagram video downloader. I manually can scrape out the link but when i try to view source page of Instagram to find link it doesn't behave as expected.

```
import requests
r = requests.get("https://www.instagram.com/instagram/")
print(r.text)
```

This above code result in:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
                  Page Not Found &bull; Instagram
                </title>

        
        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">

        
        
        

        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
  var docElement = document.documentElement;
  var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
  var className = docElement.className;
  docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
})();
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  if ('PerformanceObserver' in window && 'PerformancePaintTiming' in window) {
    window.__bufferedPerformance = [];
    var ob = new PerformanceObserver(function(e) {
      window.__bufferedPerformance.push.apply(window.__bufferedPerformance,e.getEntries());
    });
    ob.observe({entryTypes:['paint']});
  }

  window.__bufferedErrors = [];
  window.onerror = function(message, url, line, column, error) {
    window.__bufferedErrors.push({
      message: message,
      url: url,
      line: line,
      column: column,
      error: error
    });
    return false;
  };
  window.__initialData = {
    pending: true,
    waiting: []
  };
  function asyncFetchSharedData(extra) {
    var sharedDataReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sharedDataReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (sharedDataReq.readyState === 4) {
            if(sharedDataReq.status === 200){
              var sharedData = JSON.parse(sharedDataReq.responseText);
              window.__initialDataLoaded(sharedData, extra);
            }
          }
        }
    sharedDataReq.open('GET', '/data/shared_data/', true);
    sharedDataReq.send(null);
  }
  function notifyLoaded(item, data) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.data = data;
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].resolve(item.data);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  function notifyError(item, msg) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.error = new Error(msg);
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].reject(item.error);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  window.__initialDataLoaded = function(initialData, extraData) {
    if (extraData) {
      for (var key in extraData) {
        initialData[key] = extraData[key];
      }
    }
    notifyLoaded(window.__initialData, initialData);
  };
  window.__initialDataError = function(msg) {
    notifyError(window.__initialData, msg);
  };
  window.__additionalData = {};
  window.__pendingAdditionalData = function(paths) {
    for (var i = 0;i < paths.length; ++i) {
      window.__additionalData[paths[i]] = {
        pending: true,
        waiting: []
      };
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataLoaded = function(path, data) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyLoaded(window.__additionalData[path], data);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data loaded "' + path + '"');
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataError = function(path, msg) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyError(window.__additionalData[path], msg);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data encountered an error "' + path + '": ' + msg);
    }
  };
  
})();
</script><script type="text/javascript">

/*
 Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/

(function(){function g(a,c){b||(b=a,f=c,h.forEach(function(a){removeEventListener(a,l,e)}),m())}function m(){b&&f&&0<d.length&&(d.forEach(function(a){a(b,f)}),d=[])}function n(a,c){function k(){g(a,c);d()}function b(){d()}function d(){removeEventListener("pointerup",k,e);removeEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}addEventListener("pointerup",k,e);addEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}function l(a){if(a.cancelable){var c=performance.now(),b=a.timeStamp;b>c&&(c=+new Date);c-=b;"pointerdown"==a.type?n(c,
a):g(c,a)}}var e={passive:!0,capture:!0},h=["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"],b,f,d=[];h.forEach(function(a){addEventListener(a,l,e)});window.perfMetrics=window.perfMetrics||{};window.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=function(a){d.push(a);m()}})();
</script>
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/666282be8229.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png/8a5bd3f267b1.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png/68193576ffc5.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="167x167" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-167x167-precomposed.png/4985e31c9100.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-180x180-precomposed.png/c06fdb2357bd.png">
                
                    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/static/images/ico/favicon-192.png/68d99ba29cc8.png">
                
            
            
                    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/static/images/ico/favicon.svg/fc72dd4bfde8.svg" color="#262626">
                  
                  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/ico/favicon.ico/36b3ee2d91ed.ico">
                
            
            
    
        <style type="text/css">/* @generated 
 * DO NOT CHANGE THIS FILE. Instead, modify the non-build version of "main.css"
 * then run "yolo css"
 */
body{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;background-color:#fafafa;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0}.client-root{font-size:14px}a{text-decoration:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__{height:100vh}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{margin-top:137px;position:relative}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{display:block;margin-top:0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root__{background-color:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;height:77px;position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;z-index:100}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__profilePic__{display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__username__{color:#003569;display:inline!important;float:right;font-weight:400;margin-right:2px;margin-top:12px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn__{display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right:2px;margin-top:12px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText__{color:#003569;font-weight:400}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{background-image:url(/static/images/branding/logoWhiteoutLockup.png/3a62b1a95da3.png);background-size:100%;height:35px;left:16px;position:absolute;text-indent:-9999em;top:6px;width:176px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__ a{display:block;height:100%;width:100%}@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),screen and (min-resolution:1.5dppx){.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{background-image:url(/static/images/branding/logoWhiteoutLockup@2x.png/43608c988939.png)}}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logoGroup__{left:16px;position:absolute;top:6px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logoGroup__ .-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{position:static}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper__{margin:0 auto;max-width:1026px;padding:0 16px;position:relative}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ li{list-style:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__dropdown__,.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ .separator,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ .subtitle{display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__{border-right:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;width:220px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ ul{margin:0;padding:0}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__{margin:0 px;border:0;width:100%}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ ul{display:none}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__root__{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:1}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__root__{height:auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:78px;position:static}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto;margin:0 auto;position:relative;width:992px}@media screen and (min-width:991px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{height:100%}}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;height:auto;min-height:0;padding:0;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__nav__{float:left;height:100%;padding-right:0;pointer-events:initial;width:256px}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__nav__{float:none;display:block;margin:0!important;background:0 0;border:0;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #efefef;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0 16px 20px}@media screen and (min-width:991px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{border:1px solid #efefef;border-radius:3px}}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{width:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ .-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{padding:0 10px}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__{color:#262626;margin-left:205px;padding:30px 50px}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;padding:20px 0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__>:first-child{margin-top:0}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ a{color:#003569}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h1{font-size:32px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h2{font-size:24px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:12px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h3{font-weight:600;margin-bottom:12px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ li{padding-left:8px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ li:not(:first-child){margin-top:8px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ pre{white-space:pre-wrap}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__{color:#999;font-size:16px;font-weight:initial;margin:0;padding:16px;text-transform:uppercase}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__:first-child{display:block}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__:not(:first-child){display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__ i{float:left;width:22px;height:18px;margin-right:8px;margin-left:10px;background:url(/static/images/glyphs/disclosure-down@2x.png/9ae8409fbb3a.png) no-repeat center;background-size:14px 14px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__.active .-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__ i{-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);transform:rotate(180deg)}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:active,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:hover,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:visited{border-left:2px solid transparent;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;color:#262626;font-size:16px;display:block;padding:16px 16px 16px 30px;width:100%}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:hover{border-left-color:#dbdbdb}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__active__ .-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__{border-left-color:#262626;font-weight:600}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root__{font-size:12px;height:77px}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__{color:#262626;display:inline-block;float:right;font-weight:600;margin-top:20px;text-transform:uppercase}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav__{display:inline-block}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__{text-align:center;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__{margin:20px 0;padding:0;text-align:center}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ li{display:inline-block;list-style:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ li:not(:first-child){margin-left:15px}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:active,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:focus,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:hover,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:visited{color:#003569;font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper__{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;max-width:1026px;padding:0 20px}.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__{text-align:center}@media (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__{padding:100px 40px 0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__ a,.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__ a:visited{color:#003569}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__{background-color:#fff;color:#3897f0;border:1px solid #3897f0;border-radius:3px;display:inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;text-align:center;padding:8px;font:inherit;font-weight:700;width:90%}@media (min-width:736px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__{width:10%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__:active{opacity:.5}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__:focus{color:#1372cc;border:1px solid #1372cc}.-cx-PRIVATE-GatedContentPage__userAvatarContainer__{height:70px;text-align:center}.-cx-PRIVATE-GatedContentPage__userAvatar__{border-radius:50%;height:100%;width:auto}</style>
    

            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery.js/a4e77326039e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/bluebar.js/203583927eba.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    <body class=" p-error dialog-404" style="">
        
            <div class="root -cx-PRIVATE-Page__root -cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__">
                
                    <div class="page -cx-PRIVATE-Page__body -cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__">
                        
                            
                                <header class="top-bar top-bar-new -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root__">
    <div class="top-bar-wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper__">
        <div class="logo -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__"><a href="/">Instagram</a></div>

        <div class="top-bar-left -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft__">
            <ul class="top-bar-actions">
                <li>
                    <a class="top-bar-home" href="/" label=Home><i></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        
            <div class="top-bar-right account-state" id="top_bar_right">
                <ul class="top-bar-actions -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions__">
                    
                    
                      
                      <li id="link_profile" class="link-signin -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn__">
                          <a href="/accounts/login/" class="loginLink">
                              <i></i>
                              <strong class="-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText__">Log in</strong>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</header> <!-- .top-bar -->
                            
                        

                        
                        <div class="main -cx-PRIVATE-Page__main -cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__">
                            
    <div class="error-container -cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer -cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__">
    

    <h2>Error</h2>

        <p>Please wait a few minutes before you try again.</p>


    </div>

                        </div> <!-- .main -->
                        

                    </div> <!-- .page -->

                    
                    <footer class="page-footer -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root__" role="contentinfo">
                        <div class="wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper__">
                            <nav class="-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav__">
                                <ul class="-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__">
                                    <li><a href="/about/us/">About us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://help.instagram.com/">Support</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://about.instagram.com/blog/">Press</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/developer/">API</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://about.instagram.com/about-us/careers">Jobs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/legal/privacy/">Privacy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/legal/terms/">
                                      
                                          Terms
                                      
                                    </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                            <p class="copyright -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__">&copy; 2021 Instagram</p>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                    
                
                <div id="reactModalMountPoint"></div>
            </div> <!-- .root -->
        
        


        
            

            
        

        <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  function normalizeError(err) {
    var errorInfo = err.error || {};
    var getConfigProp = function(propName, defaultValueIfNotTruthy) {
      var propValue = window._sharedData && window._sharedData[propName];
      return propValue ? propValue : defaultValueIfNotTruthy;
    };
    var windowUrl = window.location.href;
    var errUrl = err.url || windowUrl;
    return {
      line: err.line || errorInfo.message || 0,
      column: err.column || 0,
      name: 'InitError',
      message: err.message || errorInfo.message || '',
      script: errorInfo.script || '',
      stack: errorInfo.stackTrace || errorInfo.stack || '',
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      ref: windowUrl.indexOf('direct') >= 0 ? 'direct' : windowUrl,
      deployment_stage: getConfigProp('deployment_stage', ''),
      frontend_env: getConfigProp('frontend_env', 'prod'),
      rollout_hash: getConfigProp('rollout_hash', ''),
      is_prerelease: window.__PRERELEASE__ || false,
      bundle_variant: getConfigProp('bundle_variant', null),
      request_url: errUrl.indexOf('direct') >= 0 ? 'direct' : errUrl,
      response_status_code: errorInfo.statusCode || 0
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (window.__bufferedErrors && window.__bufferedErrors.length) {
      if (window.caches && window.caches.keys && window.caches.delete) {
        window.caches.keys().then(function(keys) {
          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            window.caches.delete(key)
          })
        })
      }
      window.__bufferedErrors.map(function(error) {
        return normalizeError(error)
      }).forEach(function(normalizedError) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/client_error/', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        request.send(JSON.stringify(normalizedError));
      })
    }
  })
}());
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This response is different from the response when I manually go to the browser and view page source.
Any way to fix this?

Comment: use Selenium instead of requests library because Instagram detects that you are sending requests from automated software that's why it responses with that HTML.

Comment: @GiorgiImerlishvili Is there any way as I don't want to open the browser, I am planning to convert it to a web app using Django, so for simplicity, I don't want to open the browser.

Comment: It's pretty hard to scrape from sites like instagram.. I tried it with BeautifulSoup for you but it didn't output the actual site either.

Comment: @SYNEC Thanks for your efforts. That's the issue,there must be a way out...

Comment: So I found this library called insta-scrape. I don't know if you want to use this or if you want to build it from scratch. Here are the urls to the library: https://pypi.org/project/insta-scrape/  and  https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape/wiki/Scraped-data-points

Comment: @SYNEC Thanks buddy this does the work and it even made it simpler, it does the scraping itself, i wanted to do it with my own code, But its just amazing and does the work perfectly and thus want to mark it as answer, from where can i?

Comment: you can answer your question at bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found this library called insta-scrape. I don't know if you want to use this or if you want to build it from scratch. Here are the urls to the library: pypi.org/project/insta-scrape and github.com/chris-greening/instascrape/wiki/Scraped-data-points
by @SYNEC