# Instagram not returning page source

Tags: python, web-scraping, instagram

This question is an extended form of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852042/instagram-scraping-python?noredirect=1#comment118175422_66852042)

## Objective

I am trying to download Instagram video using web scraping

## What I tried?

I have tried 3 different libraries as mentioned below:

- requests
- insta-scraper
- selenium

## Results

So far i am not that much happy with the results because by using :

- *requests* i cannot view the source of instagram webpage either i run code locally or cloud(Heroku)
- *insta-scraper* i get link but only if i run code locally but not when i run on cloud.
- *Selenium* i find it functional only on my machine but not on cloud

and when i say not working, i mean instagram responds the following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js not-logged-in ">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

        <title>
                  Page Not Found &bull; Instagram
                </title>

        
        <meta name="robots" content="noimageindex, noarchive">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default">
        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
        <meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
        <link rel="manifest" href="/data/manifest.json">

        
        
        

        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
  var docElement = document.documentElement;
  var classRE = new RegExp('(^|\\s)no-js(\\s|$)');
  var className = docElement.className;
  docElement.className = className.replace(classRE, '$1js$2');
})();
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
(function() {
  if ('PerformanceObserver' in window && 'PerformancePaintTiming' in window) {
    window.__bufferedPerformance = [];
    var ob = new PerformanceObserver(function(e) {
      window.__bufferedPerformance.push.apply(window.__bufferedPerformance,e.getEntries());
    });
    ob.observe({entryTypes:['paint']});
  }

  window.__bufferedErrors = [];
  window.onerror = function(message, url, line, column, error) {
    window.__bufferedErrors.push({
      message: message,
      url: url,
      line: line,
      column: column,
      error: error
    });
    return false;
  };
  window.__initialData = {
    pending: true,
    waiting: []
  };
  function asyncFetchSharedData(extra) {
    var sharedDataReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    sharedDataReq.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (sharedDataReq.readyState === 4) {
            if(sharedDataReq.status === 200){
              var sharedData = JSON.parse(sharedDataReq.responseText);
              window.__initialDataLoaded(sharedData, extra);
            }
          }
        }
    sharedDataReq.open('GET', '/data/shared_data/', true);
    sharedDataReq.send(null);
  }
  function notifyLoaded(item, data) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.data = data;
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].resolve(item.data);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  function notifyError(item, msg) {
    item.pending = false;
    item.error = new Error(msg);
    for (var i = 0;i < item.waiting.length; ++i) {
      item.waiting[i].reject(item.error);
    }
    item.waiting = [];
  }
  window.__initialDataLoaded = function(initialData, extraData) {
    if (extraData) {
      for (var key in extraData) {
        initialData[key] = extraData[key];
      }
    }
    notifyLoaded(window.__initialData, initialData);
  };
  window.__initialDataError = function(msg) {
    notifyError(window.__initialData, msg);
  };
  window.__additionalData = {};
  window.__pendingAdditionalData = function(paths) {
    for (var i = 0;i < paths.length; ++i) {
      window.__additionalData[paths[i]] = {
        pending: true,
        waiting: []
      };
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataLoaded = function(path, data) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyLoaded(window.__additionalData[path], data);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data loaded "' + path + '"');
    }
  };
  window.__additionalDataError = function(path, msg) {
    if (path in window.__additionalData) {
      notifyError(window.__additionalData[path], msg);
    } else {
      console.error('Unexpected additional data encountered an error "' + path + '": ' + msg);
    }
  };
  
})();
</script><script type="text/javascript">

/*
 Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at

     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
*/

(function(){function g(a,c){b||(b=a,f=c,h.forEach(function(a){removeEventListener(a,l,e)}),m())}function m(){b&&f&&0<d.length&&(d.forEach(function(a){a(b,f)}),d=[])}function n(a,c){function k(){g(a,c);d()}function b(){d()}function d(){removeEventListener("pointerup",k,e);removeEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}addEventListener("pointerup",k,e);addEventListener("pointercancel",b,e)}function l(a){if(a.cancelable){var c=performance.now(),b=a.timeStamp;b>c&&(c=+new Date);c-=b;"pointerdown"==a.type?n(c,
a):g(c,a)}}var e={passive:!0,capture:!0},h=["click","mousedown","keydown","touchstart","pointerdown"],b,f,d=[];h.forEach(function(a){addEventListener(a,l,e)});window.perfMetrics=window.perfMetrics||{};window.perfMetrics.onFirstInputDelay=function(a){d.push(a);m()}})();
</script>
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="76x76" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-76x76-precomposed.png/666282be8229.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="120x120" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-120x120-precomposed.png/8a5bd3f267b1.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="152x152" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-152x152-precomposed.png/68193576ffc5.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="167x167" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-167x167-precomposed.png/4985e31c9100.png">
                <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="180x180" href="/static/images/ico/apple-touch-icon-180x180-precomposed.png/c06fdb2357bd.png">
                
                    <link rel="icon" sizes="192x192" href="/static/images/ico/favicon-192.png/68d99ba29cc8.png">
                
            
            
                    <link rel="mask-icon" href="/static/images/ico/favicon.svg/fc72dd4bfde8.svg" color="#262626">
                  
                  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/static/images/ico/favicon.ico/36b3ee2d91ed.ico">
                
            
            
    
        <style type="text/css">/* @generated 
 * DO NOT CHANGE THIS FILE. Instead, modify the non-build version of "main.css"
 * then run "yolo css"
 */
body{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;background-color:#fafafa;font-family:-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;margin:0}.client-root{font-size:14px}a{text-decoration:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:vertical;-webkit-box-direction:normal;-webkit-flex-direction:column;-ms-flex-direction:column;flex-direction:column}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__{height:100vh}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto}.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{margin-top:137px;position:relative}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__{display:block;margin-top:0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root__{background-color:#fff;border-bottom:1px solid #efefef;height:77px;position:fixed;top:0;width:100%;z-index:100}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__profilePic__{display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__username__{color:#003569;display:inline!important;float:right;font-weight:400;margin-right:2px;margin-top:12px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn__{display:inline-block;float:right;margin-right:2px;margin-top:12px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText__{color:#003569;font-weight:400}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{background-image:url(/static/images/branding/logoWhiteoutLockup.png/3a62b1a95da3.png);background-size:100%;height:35px;left:16px;position:absolute;text-indent:-9999em;top:6px;width:176px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__ a{display:block;height:100%;width:100%}@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),screen and (min-resolution:1.5dppx){.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{background-image:url(/static/images/branding/logoWhiteoutLockup@2x.png/43608c988939.png)}}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logoGroup__{left:16px;position:absolute;top:6px}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logoGroup__ .-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__{position:static}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper__{margin:0 auto;max-width:1026px;padding:0 16px;position:relative}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ li{list-style:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__dropdown__,.-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ .separator,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ .subtitle{display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__{border-right:1px solid #efefef;height:100%;width:220px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ ul{margin:0;padding:0}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__{margin:0 px;border:0;width:100%}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__ ul{display:none}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__root__{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;height:100%;pointer-events:none;position:absolute;width:100%;z-index:1}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__root__{height:auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-top:78px;position:static}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__,.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{-webkit-box-flex:1;-webkit-flex:1 0 auto;-ms-flex:1 0 auto;flex:1 0 auto;margin:0 auto;position:relative;width:992px}@media screen and (min-width:991px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{height:100%}}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__navWrapper__{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;display:inline-block;height:auto;min-height:0;padding:0;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__nav__{float:left;height:100%;padding-right:0;pointer-events:initial;width:256px}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__nav__{float:none;display:block;margin:0!important;background:0 0;border:0;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{background-color:#fff;border:1px solid #efefef;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0 16px 20px}@media screen and (min-width:991px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{border:1px solid #efefef;border-radius:3px}}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{width:100%;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ .-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__contentWrapper__{padding:0 10px}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__{color:#262626;margin-left:205px;padding:30px 50px}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__{margin-left:0;margin-right:0;padding:20px 0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__>:first-child{margin-top:0}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ a{color:#003569}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h1{font-size:32px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h2{font-size:24px;font-weight:400;margin-bottom:12px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ h3{font-weight:600;margin-bottom:12px;margin-top:28px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ li{padding-left:8px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ li:not(:first-child){margin-top:8px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__pageContent__ pre{white-space:pre-wrap}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__{color:#999;font-size:16px;font-weight:initial;margin:0;padding:16px;text-transform:uppercase}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__:first-child{display:block}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__:not(:first-child){display:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__ i{float:left;width:22px;height:18px;margin-right:8px;margin-left:10px;background:url(/static/images/glyphs/disclosure-down@2x.png/9ae8409fbb3a.png) no-repeat center;background-size:14px 14px}.-cx-PRIVATE-SidebarLayout__content__.active .-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__header__ i{-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);transform:rotate(180deg)}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:active,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:hover,.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:visited{border-left:2px solid transparent;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;color:#262626;font-size:16px;display:block;padding:16px 16px 16px 30px;width:100%}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__:hover{border-left-color:#dbdbdb}.-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__active__ .-cx-PRIVATE-Navigation__navLink__{border-left-color:#262626;font-weight:600}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root__{font-size:12px;height:77px}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__{color:#262626;display:inline-block;float:right;font-weight:600;margin-top:20px;text-transform:uppercase}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav__{display:inline-block}@media screen and (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__{text-align:center;width:100%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__{margin:20px 0;padding:0;text-align:center}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ li{display:inline-block;list-style:none}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ li:not(:first-child){margin-left:15px}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:active,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:focus,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:hover,.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__ a:visited{color:#003569;font-weight:600;text-transform:uppercase}.-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper__{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;max-width:1026px;padding:0 20px}.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__{text-align:center}@media (max-width:990px){.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__{padding:100px 40px 0}}.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__ a,.-cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__ a:visited{color:#003569}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__{background-color:#fff;color:#3897f0;border:1px solid #3897f0;border-radius:3px;display:inline-block;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;text-align:center;padding:8px;font:inherit;font-weight:700;width:90%}@media (min-width:736px){.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__{width:10%}}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__:active{opacity:.5}.-cx-PRIVATE-Linkshim__followLink__:focus{color:#1372cc;border:1px solid #1372cc}.-cx-PRIVATE-GatedContentPage__userAvatarContainer__{height:70px;text-align:center}.-cx-PRIVATE-GatedContentPage__userAvatar__{border-radius:50%;height:100%;width:auto}</style>
    

            
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/jquery.js/a4e77326039e.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/bluebar.js/203583927eba.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
    <body class=" p-error dialog-404" style="">
        
            <div class="root -cx-PRIVATE-Page__root -cx-PRIVATE-Page__root__">
                
                    <div class="page -cx-PRIVATE-Page__body -cx-PRIVATE-Page__body__">
                        
                            
                                <header class="top-bar top-bar-new -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__root__">
    <div class="top-bar-wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__wrapper__">
        <div class="logo -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__logo__"><a href="/">Instagram</a></div>

        <div class="top-bar-left -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarLeft__">
            <ul class="top-bar-actions">
                <li>
                    <a class="top-bar-home" href="/" label=Home><i></i></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        
            <div class="top-bar-right account-state" id="top_bar_right">
                <ul class="top-bar-actions -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__topBarActions__">
                    
                    
                      
                      <li id="link_profile" class="link-signin -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signIn__">
                          <a href="/accounts/login/" class="loginLink">
                              <i></i>
                              <strong class="-cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText -cx-PRIVATE-NavBar__signInText__">Log in</strong>
                          </a>
                      </li>
                      
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        
    </div>
</header> <!-- .top-bar -->
                            
                        

                        
                        <div class="main -cx-PRIVATE-Page__main -cx-PRIVATE-Page__main__">
                            
    <div class="error-container -cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer -cx-PRIVATE-ErrorPage__errorContainer__">
    

    <h2>Error</h2>

        <p>Please wait a few minutes before you try again.</p>


    </div>

                        </div> <!-- .main -->
                        

                    </div> <!-- .page -->

                    
                    <footer class="page-footer -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__root__" role="contentinfo">
                        <div class="wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__wrapper__">
                            <nav class="-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__nav__">
                                <ul class="-cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__navItems__">
                                    <li><a href="/about/us/">About us</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://help.instagram.com/">Support</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://about.instagram.com/blog/">Press</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/developer/">API</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="https://about.instagram.com/about-us/careers">Jobs</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/legal/privacy/">Privacy</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="/legal/terms/">
                                      
                                          Terms
                                      
                                    </a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>

                            <p class="copyright -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright -cx-PRIVATE-Footer__copyright__">&copy; 2021 Instagram</p>
                        </div>
                    </footer>
                    
                
                <div id="reactModalMountPoint"></div>
            </div> <!-- .root -->
        
        


        
            

            
        

        <script type="text/javascript">
(function(){
  function normalizeError(err) {
    var errorInfo = err.error || {};
    var getConfigProp = function(propName, defaultValueIfNotTruthy) {
      var propValue = window._sharedData && window._sharedData[propName];
      return propValue ? propValue : defaultValueIfNotTruthy;
    };
    var windowUrl = window.location.href;
    var errUrl = err.url || windowUrl;
    return {
      line: err.line || errorInfo.message || 0,
      column: err.column || 0,
      name: 'InitError',
      message: err.message || errorInfo.message || '',
      script: errorInfo.script || '',
      stack: errorInfo.stackTrace || errorInfo.stack || '',
      timestamp: Date.now(),
      ref: windowUrl.indexOf('direct') >= 0 ? 'direct' : windowUrl,
      deployment_stage: getConfigProp('deployment_stage', ''),
      frontend_env: getConfigProp('frontend_env', 'prod'),
      rollout_hash: getConfigProp('rollout_hash', ''),
      is_prerelease: window.__PRERELEASE__ || false,
      bundle_variant: getConfigProp('bundle_variant', null),
      request_url: errUrl.indexOf('direct') >= 0 ? 'direct' : errUrl,
      response_status_code: errorInfo.statusCode || 0
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    if (window.__bufferedErrors && window.__bufferedErrors.length) {
      if (window.caches && window.caches.keys && window.caches.delete) {
        window.caches.keys().then(function(keys) {
          keys.forEach(function(key) {
            window.caches.delete(key)
          })
        })
      }
      window.__bufferedErrors.map(function(error) {
        return normalizeError(error)
      }).forEach(function(normalizedError) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('POST', '/client_error/', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
        request.send(JSON.stringify(normalizedError));
      })
    }
  })
}());
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Problem

instagram is somehow detecting that the request is not made by human and does not responds. In case of *requests* library it totally blocks it but in case other two modules, it only work manually and insta start blocking as the code is pushed to cloud
How can I bypass this?

Comment: @snakecharmerb there are several websites they are still doing there must be a way out?

Comment: well, i'm also finding solution for this but failed yet. website are doing this but don't know how. look this https://buzzoid.com/ OR https://likes.io/

Comment: did you find any solution?